# Puppet Could not find dependency Class

Tags: puppet, configuration-management

I am trying to pull things out into roles and profiles and am having an issue. I am using puppet apply for all of this as I am using it to finish setting up my Puppet Master. If I define my node in site.pp as shown here:

```
[root@puppet puppetdbsetup]# cat manifests/site.pp
node 'puppet' {
  include ::roles::puppetmaster
}
```

I get this error:

```
[root@puppet puppetdbsetup]# puppet apply manifests/site.pp --environmentpath /etc/puppet/environments --environment puppetdbsetup --noop
Notice: Compiled catalog for puppet.belkin in environment puppetdbsetup in 1.29 seconds
Error: Could not find dependency Class[Puppet::Install] for File[/etc/puppet/hiera.yaml] at /etc/puppet/environments/puppetdbsetup/modules/p
uppet/manifests/master.pp:31
```

If I run puppetmaster.pp (shown below) with puppet apply directly it doesn't throw the same error.

```
[root@puppet puppetdbsetup]# cat modules/roles/manifests/puppetmaster.pp
class roles::puppetmaster {
  #include profiles::base
  include profiles::puppet::master
}
```

Can anyone tell me why this is and how to fix it? As a side note, all three modules referenced here are hand written... none are Forge modules.

**Update 1**
Here is my puppet::install class:

```
[root@puppet puppetdbsetup]# cat modules/puppet/manifests/install.pp
class puppet::install {

  package { 'puppet':
    ensure   => present,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your manifest, you are declaring a `File[/etc/puppet/hiera.yaml]` that depends on `Class[Puppet::Install]`, like

```
file { '/etc/puppet/hiera.yaml': require => Class['puppet::install'] }
```

or so

```
Class['puppet::install'] -> file { '/etc/puppet/hiera.yaml': ... }
```

or something in that vein.

What you are lacking is the actual declaration of the class either via

```
include puppet::install # nice!
```

or

```
class { 'puppet::install': } # please don't
```

If in doubt, add the include line near the `file` declaration. It is usually safe to include a class multiple times.

Comment: Thanks! I had `include puppet` in that manifest but it seems I needed to include both `puppet::install` and `puppet::service`.

Answer (score 0):

If you apply puppetmaster.pp directly, you're just defining the class not applying it.

You need to do `puppet apply -e 'include ::roles::puppetmaster'` to be comparible.

The other error is probably caused by modules/puppet/manifests/install.pp not existing, or the class definition in the file not starting with

```
class puppet::install (
    ....
    ....
) {
```

Comment: Running `puppet apply -e 'include ::roles::puppetmaster' --environmentpath /etc/puppet/environments --environment puppetdbsetup --noop` did not throw any errors.

Comment: I also added my puppet::install class to the original q above... any other ideas? Thanks for helping!